Looking for an old cartoon about a boy who became a pirate
I remember the main character stole his father necklace then went surfing and got sent to another world. I believe he became a pirate after that and some how have a magic sword that can talk. He also has a girl companion who is really good at fighting and has pink or purple hair

2016 is "old" now? I swear...

My name is Guybrush Threepwood, and I want to be a pirate!

Could this be Zak Storm (2016)?

When teenager Zak Storm takes his father's necklace and goes surfing,
he is suddenly sucked by a giant wave and ends up in the Bermuda
Triangle where he is picked up by a sentient pirate ship called the
Chaos with a talking sword named Calabrass. He discovers that the
necklace contains a gem called the Eye of Beru, which gives him
special powers, and that in order to return home, he needs to become
the captain of the Chaos and unite the Seven Seas. He assembles a band
of misfits: a ghost boy, an Atlantean princess, a Viking, and a space
alien.




